# WiX: Cancelling the installation doesn't remove the related subfolders from the "Program Data\Package Cache\" folder

Tags: wix

I have a bootstrapper project that chains a few msi packages and during the installation of the final setup executable if I cancel the process mid-way, then all the embedded packages are not removed/clean up from the Package Cache folder.

If I let it install successfully and then uninstall the main product then all the components (MSIs) will be uninstalled and the related folders under Package Cache will be removed as well.

How to properly handle the clean-up at the case when cancelling the installation process?